# if url contains number, add link to div

Tags: jquery

I have a set of webpages, all labelled -1, -2, -3 and so forth.
If I am on page-1, I want my button receive a new link, to page-2, and so forth.

Here is my first attempt:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("1") > -1) {
      jQuery("#nextpage").click(function() {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
  });
```

I must have written something wrong! I'd be grateful for advice.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: Using "example.com" what does the url look like?

Comment: like this: www.url.com/page-1

Comment: Actually, I want to go to the next page, alphabetically, in the WordPress structure. The above is a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regualr expression can be used to match the page and add one to it.

```js
const x = "https://www.example.com/page-2.html".replace(/(page-)(\d+)/, function (_, x, n) {
  return x + (+n + 1);
});
console.log(x);
```

So you can read the location and set the page.

```
jQuery("#nextpage").click(function() {
  window.location.href =  window.location.href.replace(/(page-)(\d+)/, function (_, x, n) {
    return x + (+n + 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: WOW. This is great! Fantastic stuff! Thanks so much!

Comment: I now succesfully added #previouspage and (+n - 1);